# Deferred initialization of immutable variables

Tags: java, constructor, immutability

I've been using scala's `lazy val` idiom a lot and I would like to achieve something similar in Java. My main problem is that to construct some value I need some other value which is not known at object construction time, but I do not want to be able to change it afterwards. The reason for that is, I'm using a GUI library which instanciates the object on my behalf and calls a different method when everything I need is created, which is when I know the values I need.

Here are the properties I try to achieve:
* Immutability of my variable.
* Initialization in some other method than the constructor.

I do not think this is possible in Java, for only `final` achieves immutability of the variable and `final` variables cannot be initialized outside of the constructor.

What would be the closest thing in Java to what I am trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be to push the actual instantiation of the value in question into another class.  This will be final, but won't be actually created until the class is loaded, which is deferred until it is needed.  Something like the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static class Loader
    {
        public static final INSTANCE = new Foo();
    }

    Foo getInstance()
    {
        return Loader.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This will lazily initialise the `Foo` as and when desired.

If you absolutely need the `Foo` to be an instance variable of your top-level class - I can't think of any way off-hand to do this.  The variable **must** be populated in the constructor, as you noted.

In fact I'm not sure exactly how Scala gets around this, but my guess would be that it sets the `lazy val` variable to some kind of *thunk* which is replaced by the actual object when first evaluated.  Scala can of course do this by subverting the normal access modifiers in this case, but I don't think you can *transparently* do this in Java.  You could declare the field to be e.g. a `Future<Foo>` which creates the value on first invocation and caches it from that point on, but that's not referentially transparent, and by the definition of `final` I don't see a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

[Andrzej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134694/deferred-initialization-of-immutable-variables/4134808#4134808) is great, but there is also a way to do it without changing the source code. Use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to capture Constructor invocations and return non-initialized objects:

```
pointcut lazyInit() : execution(* com.mycompany.expensiveservices.*.init(*));

void around()  : lazyInit() && within(@Slow *) {

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            // initialize Object in separate thread
            proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Given this aspect, all constructors of objects marked with a `@Slow` annotations will be run in a separate thread.

I did not find much reference to link to, but please read [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad/) by [Ramnivas Laddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485671/ramnivas) for more info.